# Using regular expressions to remove a string from a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to remove a string from a column using regular expressions and replace.

```
                      Name

"George @ ACkDk02gfe" sold
```

I want to remove `" @ ACkDk02gfe"`

I have tried several different variations of the code below, but I cant seem to remove string I want.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('(\@\D+\"$)','')
```

The output should be

```
George sold
```

This portion of the string `"ACkDk02gfe` is entirely random.

Comment: What is up with the down voting the answers below without comment?

Comment: @ScottBoston They're all wrong and don't actually address the question; they show a lack of knowledge with the tools being used and what the question is.  `str.replace` uses regex already; the problem is with the pattern OP has posted and I'm working on writing a correct answer now.

Comment: `df['Name'].str.replace('"','').replace('@\s\w+\s','', regex=True)` ?

Comment: @ScottBoston `regex` is `True` by default and you could combine the patterns into one, but yes, that would work as well as someone just copied your pattern into their answer 

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I know my answer isn't ideal as it is not RegEx, but it provides the correct output based off the input... and is not a horrible answer. I even prefaced my answer with "I'll let someone else post a regex answer, but this could also be done with split. I don't know how consistent the data you are looking at is, but this would work for the provided string:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this using regex with | ("OR") and regex group:

```
df['Name'].str.replace('"|(\s@\s\w+)','', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    George sold
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

#### Updated

```
df['Name'].str.replace('"|(\s@\s\w*[-]?\w+)','')
```

[image]

Where df,

```
                         Name
0  "George @ ACkDk02gfe" sold
1    "Mike @ AisBcIy-rW" sold
```

Output:

```
0    George sold
1      Mike sold
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: @excelater -rW?  I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry to clarify some of the rows has text like Mike @ AisBcIy-rW" sold. The -rW is not being removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern and syntax is wrong.

```
import pandas as pd

# set up the df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(({'Name': '"George @ ACkDk02gfe" sold'},))

# use a raw string for the pattern
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r'^"(\w+)\s@.*?"', '\\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll let someone else post a regex answer, but this could also be done with split. I don't know how consistent the data you are looking at is, but this would work for the provided string:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[0].str[1:] + ' ' + df['Name'].str.split(' ').str[-1]
```

output:

```
George sold
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do for you
Split the string by a chain of `whitespace,@,text immediately after @and whitespace after the text`. This results in a `list`. remove the list corner brackets while separating elements by space using `.str.join(' ')`

```
df.Name=df.Name.str.split('\s\@\s\w+\s').str.join(' ')



 0    George sold
```

Comment: Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

To use a regex for replacement, you need to import re and use re.sub() instead of .replace().

```
import re
                      Name

"George @ ACkDk02gfe" sold

df['Name'] = re.sub(r"@.*$", "", df['Name'])
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
ss = '"George @ ACkDk02gfe" sold'
ss = re.sub('"', "", ss)
ss = re.sub("\@\s*\w+", "", ss)
ss = re.sub("\s*", " ", ss)

George sold
```

Given that this is the general format of your code, here's what may help you understand the process I made. (1) substitute literal `"` (2) substitute given regex `\@\s*\w+` (means with literal `@` that may be followed by whitespace/s then an alphanumeric word with multiple characters) will be replaced (3) substitute multiple whitespaces with a single whitespace.

You can wrap around a function to this process which you can simply call to a column. Hope it helps!